# Mock service as a war through maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

i have a xsd conataining the request and response, i am using this xsd to create mock service and deploying as a war through **soap ui**.

but How i can do the same thing using **Maven without using Soap ui** (i should not use maven-ant-plugin)??

Is there any plugin to do that ??